# How to display textarea with button on clicking Javascript

Tags: custom-button, case, jquery

I have a custom button on case. On clicking that, it should display a text area with a button in it. I'm able to display it, but at the bottom of the detail page. I want that to be displayed in the center of the page. I don't know where I'm making mistake since I'm new to scripting.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js')}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js')} 
/*Append the jQuery CSS CDN Link to the Head tag.*/
jQuery('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />');
/*Create Alert Box HTML tag*/
var html = '<div id="alert" title="Alert"></div>';
/*Check if the Dialog(DIV Tag) already exists if not then Append the same to the Body tag.*/
if (!jQuery('[id=alert]').size()) {
  jQuery('body').append(html);
}
var CaseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case");
CaseObj.Id = '{!Case.Id}';
var caseStatus = '{!Case.Status}';
 if (caseStatus == 'Closed - Resolved') {
   var msg = "The Case is already Closed.";
   jQuery("#alert").html(msg).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function() {
            jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
 });
} else {
/*Create Confirmation Box HTML tag*/
var confBox = '<div id="confBox"></div>';
/*Check if the confBox(DIV Tag) already exists if not then Append the same to the Body tag.*/
if (!jQuery('[id=confBox]').size()) {
    jQuery('body').append(confBox);
}
var confMsg = "Are you sure you want to Close this Case?";
jQuery("#confBox").html(confMsg).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
    title: "Confirmation",
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function() {
            jQuery("#confBox").dialog("close");
            openReasonBox();
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

function openReasonBox() {
        var awesomeText = jQuery(this).html();
        var textArea = '<textarea id="myArea"></textarea>';
        if (!jQuery('[id=textArea]').size()) {
        jQuery('body').append(textArea + '<style type="text/css">.myArea{display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}</style>');
        }

}   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've posted, the openReasonBox function is looking for a textarea tag with id="myArea", and adding a style definition to it.  (Most of the other code isn't needed.)

Try adding this where you want the box to be displayed:

```
<textarea id="myArea" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: sorry for getting back late. Unfortunately your suggestion didn't work out.